# Crypting Error in java with signed bytes

Tags: java, encryption, byte, crypt

I'm trying to create a pair of function in java that has to crypts(first one funct.) a message give as an array of bytes and decrypt it(second one), by working with bytes and a simple crypting algorithm that simply functions by picking up a random byte that will be the key, adding the key to the single bytes of the messagge and append it at the end of the message. It even uses a list of prohibited byte that can't be used as key, and that's it. The problem is that i don't know why it functiones only when the key is negative(Ex: With 47 as key it doesn't decrypt correctly the message, but with -68 as the key it works).
Thanks.

```
public byte[] prohib = {33, 4, 15};

public byte[] Crypt(byte[] messTo) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    if (messTo.length <= 2) {
        return messTo;
    } else {
        byte[] crypted = new byte[messTo.length + 1];

        byte[] key_arr = new byte[1];
        new Random().nextBytes(key_arr);
        byte key = key_arr[0];

        while (ifProhib(key)) {
            System.out.println("Prohib key: " + key);

            new Random().nextBytes(key_arr);
            key = key_arr[0];
        }
        System.out.println("CryptedKey == " + key);

        for (int i = 0; i < messTo.length; i++) {
            if ((crypted[i] = (byte) (messTo[i] + key)) > 127) {
                crypted[i] = (byte) (messTo[i] + key - 255);
            } else {
                crypted[i] = (byte) (messTo[i] + key);
            }
            crypted[crypted.length - 1] = key;
        }
        return crypted;
    }
}

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] in) {

    if (in.length <= 2) {
        return in;
    } else {
        byte key = in[in.length - 1];
        byte[] decrypted = new byte[in.length - 1];

        System.out.println("DecryptedKey == " + key);
        for (int i = 0; i < decrypted.length; i++) {
            if (in[i] - key < -128) {
                decrypted[i] = (byte) (in[i] - key + 255);
            } else {
                decrypted[i] = (byte) (in[i] - key);
            }
        }
        return decrypted; //decrypted
    }
}

public boolean ifProhib(byte key) {
    for (int m = 0; m < prohib.length; m++) {
        if (key == prohib[m]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "Doesnt work" isnt a working problem description. And beyond that: what prevents you from using a debugger or more print statements, or alternatively a piece of paper, a pen and maybe a calculator ... to simply debug your code? You see: learning about programming is first of all not about writing down some code. It  is about spending hours and hours to figure why code doesn't do what you expect it to do ....